# itunes connect sandbox user wants mail verification

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have added an user under sandbox testing in itunes connect to check IAP. After logged out from App store account, when I try to put the sandbox account it wants a mail verification. Whatever as far I know, it should be a dummy account.

Comment: Yes it is a dummy account.

Comment: But it asked a mail verification..

Comment: Can't say why it is asking so without seeing how you created that. Try creating another account & use that.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I tried multiple accounts, created new ones and so on. It still wants a mail verification. Did you find any solution to this problem yet @ParthoProtimGhosh?

Comment: See: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70418

Comment: Still don't get any solution.. :(